# How to pre populate a image for taking picture in camera using Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

How can we automate the below scenario in Appium, where I need to take picture manually from the camera and then the app renders the image whether the image taken is right identity or not. how to prepopulate the images for this case instead of manually taking the picture.